# dedicated server's IP as public IP of local network without public IP

Tags: ip, tunnel, gateway

My router at home is connected to my provider using a local IP, I CANNOT have a public IP.

I have a dedicated server with a public IP.

Is it possible somehow to make that public IP the one of my home router for some services using a VPN, SSH tunnel(s), or anything else?

Thanks in advance for any advice/help!

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking. Please consider editing your question, removing extraneous details, and making a **clear** problem statement.

Comment: @EEAA is that better?

Comment: Yes, much better!

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Comment: Yes and no, I did myself a setup with a VPN and some NATing, which kinda works, but I left the question unanswered, waiting for some maybe better solution, or just other solutions. Once my setup will be stable, will post and answer here myself anyway